# Only 1st character of value in JSON is printing?

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://betkarma.com/api/propsComparison?startDate=2023-10-17&endDate=2023-10-23&league=nfl"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(response)
```

```
for player_name in data["games"][0]["offers"][0]["player"]:
    if offers[0] == "player":
        value = player["value"] 
break
print(player_name)
```

The above code appears to be correct; however, something certainly is missing in the code below. I'm expecting the first and last name of each participant, but I'm just getting the first letter of the first person's first name returned for some reason. Any assistance is highly appreciated. I'm not sure whether I'm not outputting the correct thing, if some code is missing, or what I need to do to get a list of names. I'm I'm a noob in python!

Comment: The field `player` at location *games.0.offers.0* contains a string, which is the name of the player. So if you iterate over *games.0.offers.0.player*, you're iterating letter by letter on that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import requests

url = "https://betkarma.com/api/propsComparison?startDate=2023-10-17&endDate=2023-10-23&league=nfl"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

for p in data.get("games")[0].get("offers"):
    print(p["player"])
```

output:

```
Foye Oluokun
Foye Oluokun
Michael (Saints) Thomas
Michael (Saints) Thomas
Pete Werner
Pete Werner
Demario Davis
Demario Davis
Marshon Lattimore
Demario Davis
Marshon Lattimore
Pete Werner
Marshon Lattimore
Alontae Taylor
Alontae Taylor
Alontae Taylor
Carl Granderson
Carl Granderson
Carl Granderson
Jaguars DST
Saints DST
Blake Grupe
Brandon McManus
Blake Grupe
Blake Grupe
Brandon McManus
Brandon McManus
Brandon McManus
Blake Grupe
Devin Lloyd
Devin Lloyd
Devin Lloyd
Foyesade Oluokun
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Taysom Hill
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Tank Bigsby
Alvin Kamara
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Andre Cisco
Andre Cisco
Rayshawn Jenkins
Marcus Maye
Marcus Maye
Rayshawn Jenkins
Rayshawn Jenkins
Andre Cisco
Marcus Maye
Evan Engram
Foster Moreau
Foster Moreau
Foster Moreau
Evan Engram
Evan Engram
Evan Engram
Taysom Hill
Rashid Shaheed
Michael Thomas
Chris Olave
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk
Michael Thomas
Chris Olave
Rashid Shaheed
Rashid Shaheed
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk
Calvin Ridley
```

[image: python code print images]

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
import requests

url = "https://betkarma.com/api/propsComparison?startDate=2023-10-17&endDate=2023-10-23&league=nfl"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

for p in data["games"][0]["offers"]:
    print(p["player"])
```

Prints:

```
...

Rashid Shaheed
Rashid Shaheed
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk

...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code it is very simple can you using

```py
import requests
url = "https://betkarma.com/api/propsComparison?startDate=2023-10-17&endDate=2023-10-23&league=nfl"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
players = []
for offer in data["games"][0]["offers"]:
    player_name = offer["player"]
    players.append(player_name)
for player in players:
    print(player)
```

***Output:***

```py
Foye Oluokun
Foye Oluokun
Michael (Saints) Thomas
Michael (Saints) Thomas
Pete Werner
Pete Werner
Demario Davis
Demario Davis
Marshon Lattimore
Demario Davis
Marshon Lattimore
Pete Werner
Marshon Lattimore
Alontae Taylor
Alontae Taylor
Alontae Taylor
Carl Granderson
Carl Granderson
Carl Granderson
Jaguars DST
Saints DST
Blake Grupe
Brandon McManus
Blake Grupe
Blake Grupe
Brandon McManus
Brandon McManus
Brandon McManus
Blake Grupe
Devin Lloyd
Devin Lloyd
Devin Lloyd
Foyesade Oluokun
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Trevor Lawrence
Derek Carr
Derek Carr
Taysom Hill
Trevor Lawrence
Trevor Lawrence
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Tank Bigsby
Alvin Kamara
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne Jr.
Alvin Kamara
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Travis Etienne
Andre Cisco
Andre Cisco
Rayshawn Jenkins
Marcus Maye
Marcus Maye
Rayshawn Jenkins
Rayshawn Jenkins
Andre Cisco
Marcus Maye
Evan Engram
Foster Moreau
Foster Moreau
Foster Moreau
Evan Engram
Evan Engram
Evan Engram
Taysom Hill
Rashid Shaheed
Michael Thomas
Chris Olave
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk
Michael Thomas
Chris Olave
Rashid Shaheed
Rashid Shaheed
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk
Calvin Ridley
Chris Olave
Michael Thomas
Rashid Shaheed
Rashid Shaheed
Christian Kirk
Michael Thomas
Michael Thomas
Chris Olave
Chris Olave
Calvin Ridley
Calvin Ridley
Christian Kirk
Christian Kirk
Jamal Agnew
Alvin Kamara + Evan Engram
Calvin Ridley + Chris Olave
Christian Kirk + Michael Thomas
Travis Etienne + Foster Moreau
Alvin Kamara + Travis Etienne
Calvin Ridley + Chris Olave
Christian Kirk + Rashid Shaheed
Evan Engram + Michael Thomas
Trevor Lawrence + Derek Carr
```